# Eclipse, debug, expression value

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

Is there any way to check the value of a particular expression when debugging with eclipse? The expression view isn't always that useful.

For example:

```
public class P 
{
    public boolean executed = false;

    public String getSomeString() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true; //set executed to true,so calling this method again will not yield the same result
            return "someStr";
        }else {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is main method:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P p = new P();
        p.getSomeString(); //breakpoint here, I want to check the value of this expression, but it is not assign to a variable.
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I came up with this problem when I was debugging Struts2.

in the body of `Dispatcher#serviceAction()`, there is a line `proxy.execute();` which is a String value that comes from `DefaultActionInvocation#invoke()`, basically the returned String from Actions.
But the value of `proxy.execute();` is not assigned to a variable or used anywhere inside `Dispatcher#serviceAction()`. So how is returned String from actions associated with the views?

Comment: You assign it in your `Action` implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just mark the expression an press Ctrl+Shift+I or "Run"/"Inspect" from the navigation.
Or you can use the "Display" view. Here you can write and store the expression, you want to check.

Answer (score 2):

You can check any variable value by mouse over, or just press CTRL+SHIFT+I after selecting any expression.

OR

You can add variable in watch expression of debug mode.